# How gunicorn and shared variables work

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a class that I instantiate in a request (it's a ML model that loads and takes a bit of time to configure on startup). The idea is to only do that once and have each request use the model for predictions. Does gunicorn instantiate the app every time?

Aka, will the model retrain every time a new request comes in?

Comment: You could store it in an application  global, or pickle it and put it in redis

Comment: Wait, why not just import the trained model? I'm confused...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you could benefit from the application preloading:

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app

This will let you load app code before spinning off your workers.

Comment: sounds useful. So, the implication is that it will build a new model on each request?

Comment: It will have a some activity take place at the server before you spin off worker instances so they will all have the same access.  I am not completely sure if it is a shared object or its just a copy that is just dumped into each worker.  I've found it incredibly useful when we have code where we throw away workers after x number of requests.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for how to share a variable between gunicorn workers without using **Redis** or **Session**, here is a good alternative with the awesome **[python dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)**:
The principle is to read and write shared variables from a file that could be done with `open()` but dotenv is perfect in this situation.

1. `pip install python-dotenv`
2. In app directory, create .env file:
   ├── .env
   └── app.py
   **.env**:

   ```
    var1="value1"
    var2="value2"
   ```

   **app.py**:  # flask app

```html
from flask import Flask
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

app = Flask( __name__ )

# define the path explicitly if not in same folder
#env_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) +'/../.env'
#load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)    # you may need a first load


def getdotenv(env):
    try:
        #global env_path
        #load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path,override=True)
        load_dotenv(override=True)
        val = os.getenv(env)
        return val
    except :
        return None

def setdotenv(key, value):  # string
    global env_path
    if key :
        if not value:
            value = '\'\''
        cmd = 'dotenv -f '+env_path+' set -- '+key+' '+value  # set env variable
        os.system(cmd)


@app.route('/get')
def index():
    var1 = getdotenv('var1')   # retreive value of variable var1
    return var1

@app.route('/set')
def update():
    setdotenv('newValue2')   # set variable var2='newValue2'
```